# How to pass a dynamic value from one component to the other in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a Navbar component with an anchor tag containing an onClick event. On click, a value (navvalue) is passed to the function Testfunction, which is a separate component. I want to import Testfunction into the Content component so that I can have access and display the value coming from Navbar (navvalue). How do I access “navvalue” in Content? This is an assignment in a react course I´m taking. I should use props. I´m not supposed to use either state or React Route since we haven´t reach those topics yet. Thank you for your help!

Here´s my code:

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import Content from "./Content";
import Testfunction from "./Testfunction";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar onPageChange={Testfunction} />
      <Content />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Navbar.js

```
import React from "react";


const Navbar = (props) => {
  const navvalue = "Nav Value";
  return (
    <a
      className="nav-link active text-uppercase"
      aria-current="page"
      href="#"
      onClick={() => props.onPageChange(navvalue)}
    >
      {navvalue}
    </a>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

Testfunction.js

```
const Testfunction = (navvalue) => {
  return navvalue;
};

export default Testfunction;
```

Content.js

```
import React from "react";
import Testfunction from "./Testfunction";

const Content = () => {
  const navvalue = Testfunction();

  return (
    <p>Here´s the content. Insert value coming from Navbar here: {navvalue}</p>
  );
};

export default Content;
```

Comment: Looks like your app could use a [navigation/routing library](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start) to handle sending data in route state during the navigation transition. You could start with [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and the [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), and then bigger app state management libraries like redux, depending on needs.

Comment: @DrewReese the question explicitly says *" I´m not supposed to use either state or React Route"*. Any idea how to trigger re-render of the functional components just by using props?

Comment: @TJ And? My comment was to start with other patterns like the "lifting state up to the parent" pattern with a link to the docs, in other words, OP could pass a callback. But you do have a semi-valid point.

Comment: If you can't use state or any routes, then what are the tools you've learned so far in your course? React pretty much works on just state and props.

Comment: @DrewReese The topic for this assignment is props. I should create a navbar and whenever I click on a nav item the value of the label should be displayed in a content area. The requirement is that Nabvar and Content are separate components.

Comment: So it is pretty fine to use state in this case but if your assignment says you are not supposed to use either state or React Route then you can use Redux or Context or Refs or MobX or Recoil or Akita or any other stuff (back-end?).

Answer (score 1):

To share some state in both `<Navbar />` and `<Content />` you can put state to their parent -> `App`. Also to `<Navbar />` we pass setter function to update state which is in parent.  So it can be like this:

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [navValue, setNavValue] = React.useState();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar setNavValue={setNavValue} />
      <Content navValue={navValue} />
    </div>
  );
}

const Navbar = ({ setNavValue }) => {
  const value = "Nav Value";
  return <button onClick={() => setNavValue(value)}>{value}</button>;
};

const Content = ({ navValue }) => {
  return (
    <p>Here´s the content. Insert value coming from Navbar here: {navValue}</p>
  );
};
```

Comment: The question explicitly says *" I´m not supposed to use either state or React Route"*